# Laravel 8.x returns status code 200 instead of 404 when throwing NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

After upgrading to Laravel 8.9 from 7.x, Laravel returns the wrong status code when requesting a non existing model. The response body itself contains the expected error response, however the status code is 200. Here is the corresponding controller code:

```php
public function findOne($eventId)
{
    $event = Event::withMailRecords()->withContacts()->withContingents()->findOrFail($eventId);

    return new EventResource($event);
}
```

I only get the wrong status code when starting the server using `php artisan serve` and then execute our frontend tests to query the server. Within our Laravel HTTP tests, everything works fine. Moreover, the issue only appears within our bitbucket ci pipeline. Locally everything works fine, even when executing the tests within our pipeline image.

I cannot see any environment differences that could possibly result in this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the source of your problem, but are you sure there is no space before any "<?php" tag or that you are not using encoding like UTF8 with BOM that would have already sent headers ?

Comment: The cause was an empty first line in a .php file. I however still do not understand, how this only affected our pipeline tests. Thanks so much!